# HPE Security Fortify Assessment is not showing " List of HPE Security Fortify SSC issues " in jenkins after uploading .fpr report on ssc portal

Tags: security, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, fortify

I am checking out a project from git .
Then I am building it using my own build script of maven.
I am running a fortify scan for maven project .
After that I am getting a .fpr report with help of HPE Security Fortify Assessment plugin ,it is also getting uploaded to Fortify portal .

**I want to see my report on Jenkins portal itself** .
When I am clicking " HPE Security Fortify Assessment" tab it is shoWing nothing ,rather it shows

You have to build your project in order to access Fortify Assessment results

Can some one please tell me what am I missing.

Below is the image of 
Configuration of HPE Security Fortify Assessment pluign in my jenkins 
[image: ][1][1]]

[image: List of HPE Security Fortify SSC issues scrren shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ,I got the answer .
My root project had some docker projects also to build along with maven based java projects ,and I had not installed docker on my centos machine and while building it always gave error of docker-compose: command not found which was resulting in a non-successful build internally but later on it was showing successfully because java project was built properly .
But HPE Fortify assessment plugin was giving error that Project has to build successfully ,hence I analysed the logs and installed docker-compose and docker on centos after that it started showing list of issues.